# Consider synonymizing [new-rider], [beginner], and [newbie]

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I suspect that [new-rider](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-rider) and [beginner](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) are used interchangeably. If so, they should be merged.

Conceivably, one could be "beginning" things that are not "riding," but if that's the expectation, we should make it clear in the tag guidance.

Edit: also consider [newbie](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newbie)

Answer (score 2):

Can do - which is the more "base" word here?

I'd guess that beginner --> new-rider but it could equally go the other way around.

---

I'd especially value input from people for whom English is not their Primary language.

Comment: I think that "new-rider" is more helpful as a tag.

Comment: ~~While you're in there, maybe also merge [tag:learning], yes?~~ Never mind. Some people use it for learning a specific skill.

Comment: A *beginner* could be someone starting out on repairs/maintenance rather than riding.

Comment: I would agree "new-rider" is more specific as it was mentioned that beginner could be something other than riding.  This one could miss-flag an item if changed in bulk.